# EditText.SetOnClickListener

Tags: java, android, datepicker

PatientInfo.Java

```
public class PatientInfo extends Activity {

 private Spinner locationSpinner;
 Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DateTextEdit);

   DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateLabel();
        }

    };


       edittext.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new DatePickerDialog(classname.this, date, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
        });


          private void updateLabel() {

        String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy"; //In which you need put here
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

        edittext.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
        }
```

Activity_patient_info.xml

```
    <!--  Row 2  -->
<!-- Date Of Diagnosis Row -->
    <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DiagnosisTextView"
        android:text="Date of Diagnosis"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/DateTextEdit"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:editable="false"
   android:focusable="false"
   android:onClick="setOnClickListener"
        android:hint="Choose Date" />

       <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnChangeDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Change Date" />

</TableRow>
```

I was able to get my Spinners working such that i'm able to choose the date by tapping on the edittext field. However, i could't get the datepicker working. 
The error popup was " Syntax error on token "setOnClickListener", = expected after this token"

The above solution was copied and modified from another stakeoverflow page.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Remove this line from our `Activity_patient_info.xml`
 `android:onClick="setOnClickListener"`

Reason:
you have already set onclick listener in code

if you want to declare in xml you need to do as

// in xml

```
  <TextView android:id="@+id/myview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click me!"
        android:onClick="myClickMethod" />
```

// in code

```
public void myClickMethod(View v) {
    // does something here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, check the line

```
edittext.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener() {
```

use button in place of EditText

Answer (score 0):

Code, such as calling a member function `setOnClickListener` on `edittext`, cannot be in class body. You'll need to put it in a method body.

The correct place for code like this is the `onCreate()` of an `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the line `android:onClick="setOnClickListener"` from your `.xml` file
Then put the code inside the `onCreate()` on an activity.

```
    edittext.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
// anything you want to do on click on edittext.
  }
  });
```